# How to insert (order form data) in multiple rows of mysql having same name

Tags: php, mysql

Here is code.

```
<form id="form.Id" name="form.Id" action="order" method="POST">
  <ul>
     //loading dynamically with javascript
     <li class="singalProductList'+ productId +'">
        <input type="text" value="'+ productId +'" name="dishId[]" disabled>
        <input class="newlass'+ productId +'" type="text" 
                      value="1" name="dishQuantity[]" disabled>
        <input type="text" value="'+ Name +'" name="dishName[]" disabled>
        <input type="text" value="'+ Price +'" name="dishPrice[]" disabled>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I am using MVC that's why action is (order) only.

I am submitting it with other button with Javascript that is not shown here.

I am able to get any single li having 4 input fields value without [ ].

When I use [ ] this error occur: `Notice: Undefined index: dishName in ....`.

I have used almost every code that's why I can't show any particular one.

li can be 5 or 6 but no limit.

I can use productId in every name inside [ ].

I want to insert every li that have 4 inputs in one row and others in next row in mysql.

I have problem with php side.

Thank you in advanced in case of any help.

PhP code for just dishId and dishName,

```
$dishIds = $_POST['dishId'];
$dishNames = $_POST['dishName'];

$query = $con1->prepare("INSERT INTO dishes (dish_id, dish_name) values (?, ?)");

    for ($i=0; $i<count($dishId); $i++) {

        $dishId = $dishIds[$i];
        $dishName = $dishNames[$i];

        $query->bind_param('ssi', $dishId, $dishName);
        $query->execute();
    }

    echo "Done";
    $query->close();
```

Comment: You've shown none of your php

Comment: I have added the Php code now

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump($_POST)` and pinpoint in which case you want to insert the data in msql ? Also, i dont understand some of your sentence, like "I can use productId in every name inside [ ]. ". Also, what are those "4 inputs" ? a fullfilled form ? sorry i'm confused

Comment: Sorry productId is a JavaScript variable from database. I mean I can use it inside square brackets it will be like. [1] [2] [3].... and 4 inputs mean there are 4 input fields in one li tag because I want to insert productID , productName , productQuantity, productPrice when user add single product in to cart .  I just want to insert that cart data in to database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working php code for processing Order form data and insert it in mysqli using php.

```
include 'includes/db.php';

    $did = $_POST['dishId'];
    $dqty = $_POST['dishQuantity'];
    $dname = $_POST['dishName'];
    $dprice = $_POST['dishPrice'];

    $totaldishes = sizeof($did);

    for($i=0;$i<$totaldishes;$i++) {

      $Insertdid = $did[$i];
      $Insertdqty = $dqty[$i];
      $Insertdname = $dname[$i];
      $Insertdprice = $dprice[$i];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO test (dish_id, dish_quantity ,dish_name ,dish_price)
      VALUES ('$Insertdid','$Insertdqty','$Insertdname','$Insertdprice') ";

      if ($con1->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully <br />";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con1->error;
      }
    }
```

If anyone interested and need more code or help so you can ask.